# Avoid losing focus of TextInput when parent is rerendered?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a screen with a FlatList-child. The child contains a couple of TextInputs and some styling. I want to update the parents state in the OnTextChange-function of the TextInputs. However, in my current implementation I lose focus (and keyboard is dismissed) every time I type a character in any of the TextInputs.

If I try to create a TextInput in the parent screen and update the state on every onChangeText then everything works fine.

Here is my code  (with some unimportant visual components removed):

UserInfoScreen.js

```
const onChangeText = (setUserInfo, userInfo) => (backendLabel, text) => {
  console.log(backendLabel, text);
  setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, [backendLabel]: text });
};

const UserInfoScreen = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    phoneNr: '',
  });

...

  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <SeparatedList
        onChangeText={onChangeText(setUserInfo, userInfo)}
        editable={isEditing}
        style={styles.list}
        content={[
          {
            label: 'FirstName:',
            text: userInfo.firstName,
            backendLabel: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            label: 'LastName:',
            text: userInfo.lastName,
            backendLabel: 'lastName',
          },
          { label: 'Email:', text: userInfo.email, backendLabel: 'email' },
          { label: 'Mobile:', text: userInfo.phoneNr, backendLabel: 'phoneNr' },
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

SeparatedList.js

```
const SeparatedList = ({ content, style, editable = false, onChangeText }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ ...style }}>
      <FlatList
        bounces={false}
        data={content}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.textContainer}>
              <CustomText style={styles.label}>{item.label}</CustomText>
              <TextInput
                editable={editable}
                onChangeText={text => onChangeText(item.backendLabel, text)}
              >
                <CustomText style={styles.text}> {item.text}</CustomText>
              </TextInput>
            </View>
          );
        }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <ListSeparator />}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
        keyExtractor={it => `${it.label} ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}`}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was in the row

```
keyExtractor={it => `${it.label} ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}`}
```

it worked when I instead used:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```